# Creating a Python XML to JSON converter?

Tags: python, json, xml

First of all, let me clarify and perhaps apologize, that I know the absolute bare minimum about programming, so although the answer to this is probably sort of scattered around the Internet (and believe me, I've searched), I do not understand it at all. I just need this for a project at school, and as a teenager, I do not have the funds to buy the services of a developer. Thus, I come here to ask you, so thank you so much, if anyone helps.

In Python I need to:
1) Create an HTML form that uploads an XML file
2) Convert the XML file to JSON and save it

ANY help/pointing to the right direction would be greatly appreciated, for currently I am lost.

Thank you so much again.

Comment: I'm afraid that Stack Overflow is not suited to broad questions like this. We can only really help with specific programming issues. That said, I'm not sure where best to ask this kind of question sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write one of these yourself, look [here](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/)

From the [github page](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict)

```
>>> xml = """
... <root xmlns="http://defaultns.com/"
...       xmlns:a="http://a.com/"
...       xmlns:b="http://b.com/">
...   <x>1</x>
...   <a:y>2</a:y>
...   <b:z>3</b:z>
... </root>
... """
>>> xmltodict.parse(xml, process_namespaces=True) == {
...     'http://defaultns.com/:root': {
...         'http://defaultns.com/:x': '1',
...         'http://a.com/:y': '2',
...         'http://b.com/:z': '3',
...     }
... }
True
```